# Legacy Customer Portal Users Can't Create Reports

Tags: community, reporting, customer-community, lightning-community

I'm creating a new Community using old Customer Portal Manager Custom Licences. 
After following all the steps outlined [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_reporting_external_users_report_mgmt.htm&type=5), I still cannot get the "New" button to show up for reports. Users can "Save As" but that option is very limited (you really can't change much).

So far I have:

- Verified that my user is a cloned profile that uses roles.
- Turned on enhanced sharing for reports and dashboards.
- Shared a report folder.
- Enabled field and object level permissions for the objects I'm trying to report on.
- Added all possible profile permissions related to reports, including Create and Customize Reports, Report Builder and Export Reports.
- Ensured I'm on one of the templates that work for report editing.
- Scoured the system for anything else report related and enabled it!
- Checked the report type and made sure that there was a report type that was entirely made of objects that the community user has access too.
- Verified 3 different browsers all have this issue (FF, Chrome, Safari)

Salesforce says:

> You can also give permission to all legacy role-based portal licenses, such as Customer Portal and Gold Partner.

They also say:

> External users with legacy portal licenses can create and edit reports in communities, but not in portals.

I wonder if this is perhaps what is causing it... maybe the fact that an older portal exists at all on the system prevents the newer community from allowing report edits.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Took 3 days and a good amount of luck.

Basically, you have to add a new community page called "Report Editor". It's a standard page but using the "Build Your Own" template, it's not actually there until you add it.

[image: how to add report builder]

Once you've done this and published the community... the "New Report" button shows up on the list view for reports. Done.